# SP2-0310: unable to open file "dba_files_all.sql"

Tags: sqlplus

Please advise.  This SQLPlus call:

```
SQL > @dba_files_all
```

...is not working.

> SP2-0310: unable to open file "dba_files_all.sql"

How can I resolve the error?

Comment: If you are running sqlplus from its docker container, the file must be visible through mounting.

Answer (score 11):

You need to provide the path of the file as string.

Put the path in double quotes and it will work.

For example:

```
@"C:\Users\Arpan Saini\Zions R2\Reports Statements and Notices\Patch\08312017_Patch_16.2.3.17\DB Scripts\snsp.sql";
```

Answer (score 4):

1.Use absolute path:

```
/u01/app/oaracle/test.sql
```

2.Check the path to see if script exists:

```
ls -l /u01/app/oaracle/test.sql
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this error when attempting to execute a file in the same folder as the calling function. In my example, this process:

- Was executed in **SQL Developer**;
- Has been a long-standing part of my system (moving a setup file with some settings and variable names through various folders; those folder names include the feature IDs and a short description);
- Has worked fine in the past;
- Did not require any pathing in my case because the files were in the same folder;
- Failed on the most recent attempt with the error above (**SP2-0310**).

The issue in my situation was that the folder name in which it failed included a character (`#`) that was valid for a Windows file name, but confusing to SQL Developer.

Comment: Thanks. Similar problem here: SQL Developer does not seem to recognize non-ASCII characters in file names under Linux. If such a character is in a directory name it is not even displayed as a directory in the “open” file chooser. My workaround is to create symbolic links to the concerning files.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

`SQL> @some_file.sql`

means that sql app you are using will look for that using **"absolute path"** so if you want to use **"relative path"** use following format [add ?]

`SQL> @?some_file.sql`

else, use **"full path"** with first command.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers so far imply that absolute paths are required. That aren't. Relative paths in sql is pretty universal in sql tools. Sometimes, you have to configure a lost default configuration such as in the case of SQLDeveloper as explained in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24003529/442968

Answer (score 0):

I just run into same error when I was trying to unlock **oe schema**. 
While reading the error, I realized that when I run the following line:

`>SQL @?/demo/schema/order_entry/oe_main.sql`

The error returned a completely different path

`SP2-0310: unable to open file "C:/app/USER/product/18.0.0/dbhomeXE/demo/schema/order_entry/oe_main.sql"`

Thus I copied my sql file to the path specified by the error and everything worked. I recommend that you do the same. Check the path in the error and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path or run sqlplus command from a shell/dos that points to the path of the script. Also, to use a masterscript, refer to subscripts with @@.

Answer (score -1):

verify that your file has an extension .sql not .sql.txt